# Insert an item using stored procedure

Tags: sql, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, dapper

I´m new to ASP.NET, I want to know if someone can explain how `Insert` works using a stored procedure. I'm using Dapper.

I have a product model like this:

```
using Dapper.Contrib.Extensions;
using System;

namespace Dto.Entities.Products
{
    [Table("Product.ProductDetail")]
    public class ProductDetail
    {
        [Key]
        public int ProductDetailId { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now can someone explain me how can I do an insert in controller using a stored procedure? Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest way is to handle all the logic in the controller as you said:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post([FromBody]ProductDetail payload)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection("<your_connectionstring>"))
    {
        var parameters = new
        {
            ProductId = payload.ProductId,
            Name = payload.Name,
            Description = payload.Description
        };

        await connection.ExecuteAsync("<your_insert_sp>", parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

This is not the recommended way to go though.

You should always use a [dto](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5) class instead of your real data model as the type going in or leaving your controller.

Also the db logic should be moved outside of the controller, for example to a repository class. Or you can use [Mediatr](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR) to move your logic away from your action and keep your controllers [thin](https://codeopinion.com/fat-controller-cqrs-diet/).